# Variable "error" does not exist in FOSUserBundle::layout.html.twig at line 5

Tags: php, variables, symfony

I'm working on website but I have an error when I go to 'http://localhost/Tolkien_Bestiaire/web/app_dev.php/profile/'

**error :**

> "Variable "error" does not exist in FOSUserBundle::layout.html.twig at
>   line 5"

I use FosUserBundle.

**layout.html.twig** :

```
{% extends "TolkienCoreBundle::layout.html.twig" %}

{% block body %}

    {% if error %}
        <div class="alert alert-danger">{{ error.message }}</div>
    {% endif %}

    <form action="{{ path('fos_user_security_check') }}" method="post" id="loginForm">
        <label for="username">Pseudo :</label><br/>
        <input type="text" id="username" name="_username" value="{{ last_username }}" class="col-md-4"/><br/><br/>

        <label for="password" class="col-md-12">Mot de passe :</label><br/>
        <input type="password" id="password" name="_password" class="col-md-4"/><br/><br/>

        <input type="submit" value="Connexion" class="col-md-4" />
    </form>

{% endblock %}
```

**security.yml :**

```
    security:
  encoders:
    Tolkien\UserBundle\Entity\User: sha512

  role_hierarchy:
    ROLE_ADMIN:       [ROLE_AUTEUR, ROLE_MODERATEUR]
    ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: [ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH]

  providers:
    main:
      id: fos_user.user_provider.username

  firewalls:
    dev:
      pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
      security: false
    main:
      pattern:      ^/
      anonymous:    true
      provider:     main
      form_login:
        login_path: fos_user_security_login
        check_path: fos_user_security_check
        default_target_path: tolkien_bestiaire_home
      logout:
        path:       fos_user_security_logout
        target:     /tolkien
      remember_me:
        secret:     %secret%



  access_control:
    - { path: ^/admin, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

**CoreController.php** 
(The controller of the extand to layout.html.twig) :

```
    <?php

namespace Tolkien\CoreBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

class CoreController extends Controller
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        return $this->render('TolkienCoreBundle:Core:index.html.twig');
    }

    public function contactAction(Request $request)
    {
        $session = $request->getSession();
        $session->getFlashBag()->add('info', 'La page de contact n’est pas encore disponible, merci de revenir plus tard.');

        return $this->redirectToRoute('tolkien_core_home');

    }
}
```

Thanks :)

Comment: You should use `{% if error is defined %}` instead of `{% if error %}` http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tests/defined.html

Answer (score 2):

Solution is to wrap error in another if:

```
{% if error is defined %}
{% if error %}
... do something with error message
{% endif %}
{% endif %}
```

in Login's Twig template.